# jQuery wrapper of Parsley.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

In a project, I have a lot of HTML forms without validation and I want to add a front end validation, in a quick way. I start looking for a library and I met [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/). It's a good library, but if I decided to use it I would have to modify all the forms in my application.

So there is where this code is born. It's for automatically binding a set of rules you define to a form.

```
//Only basic types and validators.
$.fn.parsley.mapping = {
//Types
'alphanum': {'parsley-type':    'alphanum'},
'email':    {'parsley-type':    'email'},
'url':  {'parsley-type':    'url'},
'number':   {'parsley-type':    'number'},
'digits':   {'parsley-type':    'digits'},
'dateIso':  {'parsley-type':    'dateIso'},
'phone':    {'parsley-type':    'phone'},

//Validators
'required': {'parsley-required':    'true'},    
'notblank': {'parsley-notblank':    'true'},
'minlength':    {'parsley-minlength': '?'},
'maxlength':    {'parsley-maxlength': '?'},
'min':  {'parsley-min': '?'},   
'max':  {'parsley-max': '?'}
}

//Only inputs and textareas
$.fn.parsley.fields = 'input:visible, textarea:visible';

!function ($) {
$.fn.generalValidation = function( validationRules ) {

var name, validations, validationName, validationValue, att, key, value
, form = $( this )
, addValidations = function( validationRules ){
if(validationRules === undefined){
console.log('Error!!! You need to add the validation rules parameter');
validationRules = {};
}
$( form ).find( $.fn.parsley.fields ).each(function(){
name = $( this ).attr('name');
validations = validationRules[name];

if(validations == undefined) return true;

for(validation in validations){
validationName = validations[validation];
validationValue = '';
if(validationName.indexOf(':') !== -1){
validationValue = validationName.substr(validationName.indexOf(':')+1, validationName.length);
validationName = validationName.substr(0, validationName.indexOf(':'));
}

att = $.fn.parsley.mapping[validationName];
if(att !== undefined){
$.map(att, function (v, k) { key = k; value = v; });
value = (value === '?') ? validationValue : value;
$(this).attr(key, value);
}
}
});
return true;
}
, callParsley = function( form ) {
form.parsley();
};

if(addValidations( validationRules )){
callParsley( form );
}
}
} ( window.jQuery );
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BV5sp/).

This is my first plugin in jQuery.  Would you improve something in the code? Do you find this useful?

Comment: I'd recommend keeping the old code embedded here.  That's more important than keeping the new code as the answers are based on the old code.

Comment: Please avoid invalidating existing answers by modifying your question with updated code. Let the answers sink in, refactor as needed, and then post the updated code in a new question. More votes for everyone! :)

Comment: @lol.upvote Thanks for pointing this. I'm going to take it into consideration next time. (I know I shouldn't say thanks :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a once over:

- The following is not DRY at all, you have to find a way to not do this:

  ```
  //Types
  'alphanum': {        'parsley-type': 'alphanum'    },
  'email': {        'parsley-type': 'email'    },
  'url': {        'parsley-type': 'url'    },
  'number': {        'parsley-type': 'number'    },
  'digits': {        'parsley-type': 'digits'    },
  'dateIso': {        'parsley-type': 'dateIso'    },
  'phone': {        'parsley-type': 'phone'    },
  ```

  I am pretty sure you can throw all that way by changing to the below statement:

  ```
  att = $.fn.parsley.mapping[validationName] || {  'parsley-type': validationName  };
  ```
- Also, `$.fn.parsley.mapping` could use some aligning to look better
- You are calling `$.map` without capturing the array it returns, perhaps you meant to use `forEach` ? Also, it seems that your code will not work correctly if there is more than 1 property in `parsley.mapping`.You keep assign to the same `key` and `value`.
- Your `var` statement is too messy:

  ```
  var name, validations, validationName, validationValue, att, key, value, form = $(this),
      addValidations = function (validationRules) {
  ```
- Comparisons with `undefined` should be either with `===` or by doing a falsey check so use either `if(validations === undefined)` or `if(!validations)`
- There is no `var validation` for `for(validation in validations){`
- There are plenty of comma and semicolon problems, you should use jshint to find & solve them

All in all, I like the value of your wrapper, but I think it needs some more polishing.

Comment: @konjin I just update my question with the new code following some of your suggestions and JSHint. I can't figure it out how to get rid of the map function in the for, both (you and JSHint) don't like it haha.

Answer (score 1):

What about jquery validate?
You shouldn't have to change any forms... If you're changing the form to accommodate the JavaScript you're not doing it right.

Comment: Hey, all the plugins or whatever I looked you have to modify your form and add the rules for the validation. Can you point me out one that does not require that? (Googled jquery validate but I don't know what are you referring)

Comment: Read the first two paragraphs: http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/. You can set the rules in an object that is passed to validate () rather than in the form.